# How do I return my ActionResult to the proper view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have a MVC 3 web application (more like a sub-application, really) that does not rely on ASPNET for authentication because that is already being used in another area of the app and we are using a different type of credentialing. At any rate, I decided to create my own authentication system with its own SQL table, which is working fine on one form in the app. Now, I am trying to roll it into the shared layout, calling a "Login" action in the home controller. The problem I am having is how to return from that Login action back to wherever the user is. When I try "return View();" it understandably tries to return to a Home/Login view, which doesn't exist. How do I return from this Action to wherever I was before the action? All views use the shared layout, so I'm hoping this is fairly simple!

```
public class HomeController : Controller       
{

 .....

    private DataModel db = new DataModel();

    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {

        string un = Request["form_un"];
        string pc = Request["form_pc"];
        int usercount = db.JobBoardUsers.Where(u => u.userid.Equals(un) && u.passcode.Equals(pc)).Select(u => new AccountModel() { uid = u.id }).Count();
        usercount = db.JobBoardUsers.Where(u => u.userid.Equals(un) && u.passcode.Equals(pc)).Count();
        if (usercount > 0)
        {
            HttpContext.Session["IsSignedIn"] = true;
            HttpContext.Session["IsSignedInId"] = un;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Do you explicitly go to the `Login` view (i.e. are you calling this action or does the server redirect the unauthenticated user)? Depending on your logic, you could use `Request.Path` to determine the targeted address. Or even `Request.UrlReferrer`.

Comment: It is explicit. The action on the login form is "Home/Login". The app is fully usable without authenticating (login provides some additional features, like remembering the user's information), so I would not want to automatically redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `return View()`, You need to use return `RedirectToAction` or return `Redirect` method.

You may get the previous page in your login action using different methods

1) pass the current pages url to login action method as a parameter and use that for redirecting after successful authentication

2)Use the Request object to get the UrlReferrer property value and use that as the page to be redirected.

Chek this [blog post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks) where they explains how they did it in nerddinner.

Comment: Thank you, I went with #2 and it works perfectly. I would have figured MVC had a more convoluted standard for doing this like it seems to with everything else.